# RadioGroup with radio buttons in different layouts

Tags: android

Is it possible to have a radio group with radio buttons in their own layouts? Every radio button has to be on a row that contains text and an image. I wouldn't use a list view because I only have 2 rows.

Answer (score 8):

**Here is the way to do it:**

Create a separate `RadioGroup` on each `RadioButton` in the XML layout file. For example:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rdoFooWrapper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdoFoo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rdoBooWrapper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdoBoo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Now, inside the java source code, do something like this:

```
rdoFooWrapper = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdoFooWrapper);
rdoFoo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdoFoo);
rdoBooWrapper = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdoBooWrapper);
rdoBoo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdoBoo);

rdoFoo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this); // implement OnCheckedChangeListener to the current class
rdoBoo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

// ...

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
{
    rdoFooWrapper.clearCheck();
    rdoBooWrapper.clearCheck();
}
```